# Numerical computation of a spectrum of the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

I'm working with $L_2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and I have operators of the form

$$ H = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m} \Delta + V(x_1, \dots, x_n) $$

where $V(x)$ can be very involved dependence on $x$.

What's a good algorithm to use for computing the spectra of such operators?

Here's what I'm looking for in such an algorithm:

1. I only care about the eigenvalues and generalized eigenvalues that lie in an arbitrary interval $[E_{lo}, E_{hi}]$.
2. I don't need to be able to distinguish between continuous spectrum and tightly clustered together isolated eigenvalues.
3. Need to have decent accuracy.
4. I'm mostly interested in systems with $n < 10$, so it can grow exponentially in complexity with $n$ that's fine.

Comment: I can give a few options for finding energy levels in ascending order starting with the groundstate. And in general the numerical stability will get worse with higher excited states. So if your $E_{lo}$ is very far from the groundstate this won't be helpful. Are you interested in this?

Comment: I can give another option that will only work on a finite hilbert space (so a smaller number of degrees of freedom), which will work depending on how localized you expect these states to be. I'm not sure you'll get a usable answer with how general your question is.

Comment: @AndrewChristensen I am interested in operators defined on $L_2$, a finite-dimensional vector space case is trivial (simply find the eigenvalues of a matrix).